# ids for this/ class must be manually/ assigned before calling save()

Tags: hibernate

i want to save a member in my database. I annotated my id such as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id",unique=true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
```

part of the hbm.xml:

```
<id name="id" type="native">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
```

i tried to add the id manually...but isnt working...what am i doing wrong here?

here is the method:

```
public Member save() throws ClassNotFoundException, HibernateException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Member member=new Member();
    member.setName(this.name);
    member.setSurname(this.surname);
    member.setEmail(this.email);
    member.setUsername(this.username);
    member.setPassword(this.password);

    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(member);


    session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.close();
```

Comment: More information is needed.  What database?  What specific error message or behavior?

Comment: Why do you use annotations and hbm mapping files together? Just remove the annotations, the file should do its work.

Comment: same exception...do i have to set the id manually..??

Comment: Or rather, just remove the XML files: the annotations are sufficient. Really, XML files are proprietary, pre-Java5 artefacts that aren't needed anymore.